# System of equations using the elimination Method

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the system of equations using the Elimination Method.

$3x-4y+0z=63$

$-2x-1y+0z=-9$

$5x-3y+0z=72$

I have tried this a couple of times and can't find my $z$ value

Comment: The equations you have written have no $z$. Please correct the question, show what you have tried.

Comment: So for my answer I got x=9, y=9 and z=0 because there is no z, but I get the answer as wrong

Comment: You should get x = 9 and y = -9.  z can take any value.

Comment: Welcome to Math.S.E. You have incorrectly copied the equations, there is no '$z$' in the equations anywhere. Kindly add the details to get your answer quicker

Comment: my question says it takes a numerical answer... how could I represent that than

Comment: but my question asks for a z value, this is why I am confused

Comment: the answer you will find in the comments